# React JS : run start won't work. Problem with babel-eslint dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, eslint

I am starting react JS and I created a new project but I have a problem running it.
I tried with a different version of node. Now, I am using v14.17.6
This is the message I get :

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
> likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
> locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of babel-eslint was
> detected higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\node_modules\babel-eslint (version: 10.0.3)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
> hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
> permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
> order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
> not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if C:\node_modules\babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
>    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
>    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
> in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
> in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
> We hope you find them helpful!
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! mfsitexxx@0.1.0
> start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the mfsitexxx@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably
> not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\waref\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-22T15_03_49_372Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\waref\Documents\GitHub\mfsitexxx>

Comment: Have you followed the steps to check/fix the dependency tree?

Comment: Yes I did try it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems from the error message that you are missing dependencies. Try running the following commands

```
npm install eslint@6.x babel-eslint@10 --save-dev
```

Comment: I did it and I just tried that again and it's still not working for some reason